# Pandas - How to insert a new column with the count when there are multiple clauses

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following excel sheet, which I've imported into pandas using read_csv

```
df
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Order ID</th><th>Platform</th><th>Media Source</th><th>Campaign</th><th>1st order</th><th>Order fulfilled</th><th>Date</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Web</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>FALSE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>2/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Web</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>FALSE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>2/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp2</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp2</td><td>FALSE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>2/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to add a new column NewOrderForDate which gives me a count of all the orders for that campaign for that date AND 1st Order = TRUE

Here's how the dataframe should look after adding this column

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Order ID</th><th>Platform</th><th>Media Source</th><th>Campaign</th><th>1st order</th><th>Order fulfilled</th><th>Date</th><th>NewOrderForDate </th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>FALSE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Web</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>FALSE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>2/1/2019</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Web</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>2/1/2019</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp2</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Facebook</td><td>FBCmp</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>Web</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp2</td><td>TRUE</td><td>FALSE</td><td>2/1/2019</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>TRUE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>Mobile</td><td>Google</td><td>Cmp1</td><td>FALSE</td><td>TRUE</td><td>1/1/2019</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

If I had to do this in Excel, I'd probably use

```
=COUNTIFS(G$2:G$11,G2,E$2:E$11,"TRUE")
```

Basically, I want to group by column and date and get a count of all the orders where 1st order = TRUE and write these values to a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupBy `'Campaign'`, count the `'1st order'` and add `'NewOrderForDate'` column for each group.

```
def udf(grp_df):
    grp_df['NewOrderForDate'] = len(grp_df[grp_df['1st order']==True])
    return grp_df
result = df.groupby('Campaign', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(udf)
```

Comment: I had to group by both, campaign and date and then get the count of 1st order == True.

Adding 'Date' to the groupby worked for me.

I'll update in case I face any other issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` to keep the index shape, and sum the `bool` value of 1st Order:

```
df['NewOrderForDate'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Campaign'])['1st order'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```